# Print function that returns int

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I am trying to print a method which returns an `Int`. For now, `mySum` is just a stub because I'm trying to figure out how to print it.

I looked up how to do this and I saw `putStr` can print a `String` and show converts an `Int` to a `String` so I did this:

```
mySum :: [Int] -> Int
mySum _ = 0

main = putStr show mySum [1..5]
```

However, I am getting these errors:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘([Int] -> Int) -> [Integer] -> t’
                with actual type ‘IO ()’
    Relevant bindings include main :: t (bound at weirdFold.hs:10:1)
    The function ‘putStr’ is applied to three arguments,
    but its type ‘String -> IO ()’ has only one
    In the expression: putStr show mySum [1 .. 5]
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = putStr show mySum [1 .. 5]
```

and

```
Couldn't match type ‘a0 -> String’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: String
  Actual type: a0 -> String
Probable cause: ‘show’ is applied to too few arguments
In the first argument of ‘putStr’, namely ‘show’
In the expression: putStr show mySum [1 .. 5]
```

So how can I actually print the result of the method?

Comment: try adding some parentheses: `main = putStr (show (mySum [1..5]))`. function application is left associative.

Comment: First impression of the title: you are trying to print a function (not the value you get when you apply the function). You could easily arrive at the solution by realizing that you want to simply print an `Int` not a function. Like `print n` (`print = putStrLn . show`) and then substitute for `n`: `print (mySum [1..5])`. I used `print` for simplicity but you can just as easily use `putStr . show` or anything else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because function application is left-associative, `putStr show mySum [1..5]` is implicitly parenthesized as `((putStr show) mySum) [1..5]`. There are a few options; some are listed below.

1. Parenthesize explicitly: `putStr (show (mySum [1..5]))`
2. Use the *right*-associative function application operator `$`; one example is `putStr $ show (mySum [1..5])`
3. Use composition with `$`: `putStr . show . mySum $ [1..5]`
4. Use composition with parentheses: `(putStr . show . mySum) [1..5]`

Comment: This is all great advice (I upvoted the answer), but I have to ask, why the hybrid answer for number 2....  If using the `($)`, why not go the whole way with `putStr $ show $ mySum [1..5]`?

Comment: I was thinking `putStr $ show $ mySum $ [1..5]` (although the last one is really unnecessary) would be too much new operator at once, so limited myself to using it just once to replace one set of parentheses.